# Помогите понять ошибку в вычислениях программы

Tags: python, арифметика

Я написал код:

```
x = 6
y = 8
for i in range(9):
    x = x * y / (x * 2.5) * (2.5 + i * 0.1)
    print("x =", x)
    print("y =", y)
    y = x
```

Программа выдаёт:
**x = 7.5** ...
А первый Х точно долен быть **6 × 8 ÷ (6 × 2.5) × 2.6 = 8.32**
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не выдаёт она 7.5. Первая итерация даст в результате 8. Что, естественно, правильно. `6 × 8 ÷ (6 × 2.5) × 2.5 = 8`

Comment: В первой итерации `i` равен нулю

Comment: Можете пояснить. Я не особо понял

Comment: а всё спасибо!!

Comment: При `i` равным нулю для первой итерации - `(2.5 + 0 * 0.1) = 2.5`

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку все итерации в `for` начинаются с 0 (если не указано иное), то при первой итерации `i = 0`. Тогда мы можем подсчитать `x`:

```
x = 6 * 8 / (6 * 2.5) * (2.5 + 0 * 0.1)
x = 48 / 15 * 2.5
x = 8.0
```

А вообще у Вас не может получиться `x = 7.5`, потому что оператор `/` в Python 3.x обозначает обычное деление с получением вещественного числа. Впрочем, в Python 2.x данный оператор таки обозначал деление нацело, однако синтаксис всё же указывает на 3.x.

В любом случае, `i` в начале цикла равен 0, и так происходит всякий раз, когда Вы передаёте в `for` один параметр (если их будет два, то `i` пойдёт с первого параметра на второй, тогда уже `i` может начинаться не с 0).